# Charts API error -- [one or more participants failed to draw()]

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am currently experiencing --> [one or more participants failed to draw()] error on the client side.  I am able to get data to output in the drawVisualisation call, hence the issue is within the javascript code.  I followed example but I cannot seem to figure out where I may be going wrong to trigger the error.

```
 function drawVisualization(dataValues, chartTitle, columnNames, categoryCaption) {
        if (dataValues.length < 1)
            return;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[0]);
        data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[1]);
        data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[2]);

        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {

            data.addRow([dataValues[i].Type, dataValues[i].PType, dataValues[i].COUNT]);
        }



        var line = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
            'containerId': 'chart1',
            'options': {
                'width': '1200',
                'height': '500',
                'legend': 'none'
            },

            'view': { 'columns': [2, 0] }
        });

       var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'Table',
            'containerId': 'chart2',
            'options': { 'height': '25em', 'width': '80em' }
        });

        var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
            'containerId': 'Contorl1',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnLabel': columnNames.split(',')[1],
                'filterColumnIndex': '1',

                'ui': {

                    'label': 'Price'
                }
            }

        });

        new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('PieChartExample')).bind([categoryPicker], [line, table]).draw(data);

    }
  </script>

   <div id="PieChartExample">
        <table>
            <tr style='vertical-align: top'>

                <td >
                    <div style="float: left;" id="chart1"></div>    

                </td>

            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td >
                <div style="float: left;" id="chart2"></div>    

                </td>

            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style='width: 600px'>

                <div style="float: left;" id="control2"></div>   
                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>         
    </div>
```

Server side code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "TestInitPageScript",

       string.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\">google.load('visualization','1.0',{{'packages':['corechart','controls']}});google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){{drawVisualization({0},'{1}','{2}');}});</script>",
        jss.Serialize(GetData()),
    "Name Example",
     "Type,"));

    }
}

[WebMethod]
public static List<Data3> GetData()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("##############");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    conn.Open();
    string cmdstr = "SELECT [Type], Cover, COUNT(Cover)  AS 'Total' FROM [dbo].[database_qy] WHERE [Type] in ('bs','as') GROUP BY Cover, [Type] order by Cover";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    List<Data3> dataList = new List<Data3>();
    string cov = "";
    string typ = "";
    int val = 0;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        try
        {
            cov = dr[0].ToString();

            typ = dr[1].ToString();

            val = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        dataList.Add(new Data3(cov, typ, val));
    }
    return dataList;
}
```

I am also getting returned to drawVisualisation call, as shown below;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">google.load('visualization','1.0',{'packages':  ['corechart','controls']});google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawVisualization([{"Type":"bs","PType":"cv","COUNT":2576},{"Type":"cd","PType":"cv","COUNT":2056},{"Type":"cl","PType":"cv","COUNT":9901},{"Type":"cm","PType":"cv","COUNT":10079},{"Type":"rm","PType":"cv","COUNT":12242},{"Type":"bs","PType":"tk","COUNT":3678},{"Type":"cd","PType":"tk","COUNT":7567},{"Type":"cl","PType":"tk","COUNT":42976},{"Type":"cm","PType":"tk","COUNT":21245},{"Type":"rm","PType":"tk","COUNT":44379},{"Type":"bs","PType":"TRD","COUNT":7},{"Type":"cd","PType":"TRD","COUNT":50},{"Type":"cl","PType":"TRD","COUNT":86},{"Type":"cm","PType":"TRD","COUNT":202},{"Type":"rm","PType":"TRD","COUNT":116}],'Name Example','Type,');});</script></form>
```

Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Please update your answer with sufficient code to replicate the problem.  We can't test your code without examples for `dataValues`, `chartTitle`, `columnNames`, and `categoryCaption`.

Comment: Apology for not making my problem not clear, I have updated my question with the relevant information as request.  I am sadly still getting `One or more participants failed to draw()`, on the client-side. i have tested the server side code and the data is returned to the array, so it may be something in java script code? Thank you for  response and help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `line` ChartWrapper's view.  The columns you specified (`[2, 0]`) do not work, as column 0 is a "string" type and cannot be a data series in the chart.  Change it to `[0, 2]` and the dashboard will draw.

```
var line = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'containerId': 'chart1',
    'options': {
        'width': '1200',
        'height': '500',
        'legend': 'none'
    },
    'view': { 'columns': [0, 2] }
});
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/8D64L/